# Synonym request for [record-of-agarest-war] ↔ [agarest-generations-of-war] and others in series

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, we have questions like [How do I beat the Golem Boss in Tymmer Palace Ruins in Agarest - Generations of War ZERO?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/80704/47878), which refers to the European name for the game (*Agarest: Generations of War Zero*), but which is tagged with [record-of-agarest-war-zero](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/record-of-agarest-war-zero), the North American name for the game (*Record of Agarest War Zero*).

Given that there is this confusion, I think we should have tag synonyms for the games in this series. I think that the North American names for the games should remain as the "parent" tag because that's what the English-language Wikipedia articles use (e.g. [Record of Agarest War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_of_Agarest_War)).

Could we please have the following tag synonyms?

- [record-of-agarest-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/record-of-agarest-war) ↔ [agarest-generations-of-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agarest-generations-of-war)
- [record-of-agarest-war-zero](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/record-of-agarest-war-zero) ↔ [agarest-generations-of-war-zero](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agarest-generations-of-war-zero)
- [record-of-agarest-war-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/record-of-agarest-war-2) ↔ [agarest-generations-of-war-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agarest-generations-of-war-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seens sensible. Synonyms added:

- [agarest-generations-of-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agarest-generations-of-war) → [record-of-agarest-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/record-of-agarest-war)
- [agarest-generations-of-war-zero](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agarest-generations-of-war-zero) → [record-of-agarest-war-zero](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/record-of-agarest-war-zero)
- [agarest-generations-of-war-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agarest-generations-of-war-2) → [record-of-agarest-war-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/record-of-agarest-war-2)